# JEST beforeAll scope with .only

Tags: jestjs

Can anybody explain why the code in BeforeAll of the first Describe block is executed here

```
describe("Describe1", () => {

    beforeAll(async () => {
        console.info("beforeAll  for Describe1");
    });

    test("Test1", async () => {
        console.info("test1 for Describe1");
    });
});

describe.only("Describe2", () => {

    beforeAll(async () => {
        console.info("beforeAll  for Describe2");
    });

    test("Test1", async () => {
        console.info("test1 for Describe2");
    });
});
```

In my opinion only code inside Describe2 has to be executed here...